# Executing rails command in Dockerfile results in different result than executing locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile

It seems that my Dockerfile has some issues when executing commands

This worked fine until Docker introduced their new docker build system. (Working on OSX)

[image]

```
#20 [16/20] RUN bundle exec rails assets:precompile
#20 sha256:07d4070bb6941b1c5cb27c2009c376ca5e1ce4b696896539e17f35865e416655
#20 0.502 Usage:
#20 0.502   rails new APP_PATH [options]
#20 0.502 
#20 0.502 Options:
#20 0.502       [--skip-namespace], [--no-skip-namespace]              # Skip namespace (affects only isolated engines)
#20 0.502       [--skip-collision-check], [--no-skip-collision-check]  # Skip collision check
#20 0.502   -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                          # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
#20 0.502                                                              # Default: /usr/local/bin/ruby
#20 0.502   -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                                  # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
#20 0.502   -d, [--database=DATABASE]                                  # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/postgresql/sqlite3/oracle/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
#20 0.502                                                              # Default: sqlite3
#20 0.502       [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]                  # Don't create a Gemfile
#20 0.502   -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                          # Skip .gitignore file
#20 0.502       [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                      # Skip source control .keep files
#20 0.502   -M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]      # Skip Action Mailer files
#20 0.502       [--skip-action-mailbox], [--no-skip-action-mailbox]    # Skip Action Mailbox gem
#20 0.502       [--skip-action-text], [--no-skip-action-text]          # Skip Action Text gem
#20 0.502   -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]      # Skip Active Record files
#20 0.502       [--skip-active-job], [--no-skip-active-job]            # Skip Active Job
#20 0.502       [--skip-active-storage], [--no-skip-active-storage]    # Skip Active Storage files
#20 0.502   -P, [--skip-puma], [--no-skip-puma]                        # Skip Puma related files
#20 0.502   -C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]        # Skip Action Cable files
#20 0.502   -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]              # Skip Sprockets files
#20 0.502       [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                    # Don't install Spring application preloader
#20 0.502       [--skip-listen], [--no-skip-listen]                    # Don't generate configuration that depends on the listen gem
#20 0.502   -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]            # Skip JavaScript files
#20 0.502       [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]            # Skip turbolinks gem
#20 0.502       [--skip-jbuilder], [--no-skip-jbuilder]                # Skip jbuilder gem
#20 0.502   -T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                        # Skip test files
#20 0.502       [--skip-system-test], [--no-skip-system-test]          # Skip system test files
#20 0.502       [--skip-bootsnap], [--no-skip-bootsnap]                # Skip bootsnap gem
#20 0.502       [--dev], [--no-dev]                                    # Set up the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
#20 0.502       [--edge], [--no-edge]                                  # Set up the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
#20 0.502       [--master], [--no-master]                              # Set up the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository main branch
#20 0.502       [--rc=RC]                                              # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
#20 0.502       [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                                # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
#20 0.502       [--api], [--no-api]                                    # Preconfigure smaller stack for API only apps
#20 0.502       [--minimal], [--no-minimal]                            # Preconfigure a minimal rails app
#20 0.502   -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                    # Don't run bundle install
#20 0.502   --webpacker, [--webpack=WEBPACK]                           # Preconfigure Webpack with a particular framework (options: react, vue, angular, elm, stimulus)
#20 0.502       [--skip-webpack-install], [--no-skip-webpack-install]  # Don't run Webpack install
#20 0.502 
#20 0.502 Runtime options:
#20 0.502   -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
#20 0.502   -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
#20 0.502   -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
#20 0.502   -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist
#20 0.502 
#20 0.502 Rails options:
#20 0.502   -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
#20 0.502   -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
#20 0.502 
#20 0.502 Description:
#20 0.502     The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
#20 0.502     directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.
#20 0.502 
#20 0.502     You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
#20 0.502     'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory,
#20 0.502     or in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/rails/railsrc if XDG_CONFIG_HOME is set.
#20 0.502 
#20 0.502     Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
#20 0.502     defaults values shown above in this help message.
#20 0.502 
#20 0.502 Example:
#20 0.502     rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog
#20 0.502 
#20 0.502     This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
#20 DONE 0.5s
```

TLDR:

`RUN bundle exec rails assets:precompile` thinks it executs `rails new APP_PATH [options]`

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Sorry guys, I dont know what to say more. It seems I have to fight programs that thinks they are smarther than me. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: My guess -- without seeing your docker file prior to the RUN command -- is that the command is not running in the context of your rails application.

Comment: `Sorry guys, I dont know what to say more` <= a Dockerfile to start with and as already mentioned in the above comment would be strict minimum. You'll also want to read [How to ask](/help/howt-to-ask) and [Creating a minimal example](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in the wrong directory, it seems rails does not detect what command you entered and always reply with `rails new` error message.

So be sure you are in a rails directory.